# Response is null after Http POST request in angular 7

Tags: angular, rest, http, glassfish

I am trying to send two data to my RESTful server running on glassfish. The user has to select a restaurant in the datalist. I want to send an id and a name of the restaurant. With console.log I can print out the values of the id and name, but my response returns null. Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

ts file

```
export class OrganizeComponent implements OnInit {

  public codeValue: string;

  codeList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mcdonalds' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Kentucky Fried Chicken' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Burger King' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Domino`s pizza' },
    { id: 5, name: 'New York Pizza' }
  ];


  @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
  restaurant = {
    id: 0,
    name: ''
  };



  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public saveCode(e): void {
    let name = e.target.value;
    let list = this.codeList.filter(x => x.name === name)[0];
    // console.log(list.id);
    // console.log(list.name)


    this.restaurant.id =  list.id;
    this.restaurant.name = list.name;

console.log(list.id);
console.log(list.name);

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant', {
      id: list.id,
      name: list.name
    })


      .subscribe( // subscribe to observable http.post
        res => {
          console.log("response" + " " + res); // log results otherwise log error
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        }
      );
```

Html file

```
<label for="codes">Choose a restaurant:</label>
    <form
      (ngSubmit)="onOrganize(f)"
      #f="ngForm">
      <input type="text"  list="codes"  [(ngModel)]=codeValue [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="saveCode($event)">
      <datalist id="codes">
        <option *ngFor="let c of codeList" [value]="c.name" >{{c.name}}</option>
      </datalist>
    </form>
```

Backend code:

```
@Stateless
@Path("restaurant")
public class RestaurantResource {

    @Inject
    private RepositoryService repositoryService;

    @GET
    @Path("restaurant")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response all(){
        List<Restaurant> all = repositoryService.getAllRestaurants();
        return Response
                .status(200)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .entity(all)
                .build();
    }


    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Restaurant> getAllRestaurants(){
        return repositoryService.getAllRestaurants();

    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response save(Restaurant restaurant){
        repositoryService.save(restaurant);
        return Response
                .status(201)
                .build();
    }
```

```
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="idRestaurant")
    @NotBlank
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;



    public Restaurant(Integer id,Integer restaurantId , String naam) {
        this.id = id;
        this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
        this.naam = naam;
    }
```

Error in backend service:

> internal server error 500. A system exception occurred during an
>   invocation on EJB RepositoryService, method: public void
>   nl.aquadine.service.RepositoryService.save(nl.aquadine.model.Restaurant)]]
>   and javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown
>   from bean and Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException:
>   detached entity passed to persist: nl.aquadine.model.Restaurant at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
>   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersis etc.

Comment: If the response is null, you have to check in your backend what is Happening there. You have to debug the backend, not thr frontend (the Angular app).

Comment: If you are aiming to send through JSON, then you are missing the correct headers

Comment: @jcuypers the Angular Http Client sets the headers for a json post. It is the defau8lt behaviour from this lib. More here: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: I added some backend code. I cant seem to find the error

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I don't see where I can find it to be the default behavior.  It is nowhere written and the examples also specify the header.  The heroes example has some basic headers defined which are included every time in each call.  this is not default behavior

Comment: you perform a console.log in your front-end. this doesn't mean anything for backend. add debugging code to confirm you get the same values in your backend.  if not, troubleshoot whether you are sending the values as correct JSON

Comment: Aren't you getting any logging on the backend side as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your code

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

const data = {
   id: list.id,
   name: list.name
};

  this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant', 
      JSON.stringify(data), httpOptions)
```

Comment: another point might be that you need a correct CORS policy so you can accept this pre-flight type of request.  Meaning you are willing to accept OPTIONS method, besides GET / POST (this is what postman doesn't generate btw... OPTIONS/204)

Comment: When I use the http post verb now, I get a internal server error 500 all the time with the old and new code. I added the errors in my other comment

Comment: ok remove the save method temporarily and see what you get. try to dump the variables to see if they are existing

Answer (score -2):

1. First test with POSTMAN or any other toll to test your backend response if its working fine then you may focus on front end.

Comment: yes and no.  postman doesn't correctly emulate pre-flight behavior and this should be a comment. not an answer